# Autofac to Ninject

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container, autofac

In order to set unified standard in all my development I created a Core lib.
One of the main features is to send Action<...> to dependency registrar that based on Autfac.
I would like to move to ninject.

I'm currently stuck in giving a binding key (id) and send a collection of parameters to binding.

The Autofac code is:

```
public void AddComponentWithParameters(Type service, 
    Type implementation, IDictionary<string, string> properties, 
    string key = "")
{
    UpdateContainer(x =>
    {
        var serviceTypes = new List<Type> { service };

        var temp = x.RegisterType(implementation)
            .As(serviceTypes.ToArray())
            .WithParameters(properties
            .Select(y => new NamedParameter(y.Key, y.Value)));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            temp.Keyed(key, service);
        }
    });
}
```

The ninject code:

```
public void AddComponentWithParameters(Type service, 
    Type implementation, 
    IDictionary<string, string> properties, string key = "")
{
    UpdateContainer(x =>
    {
        var serviceTypes = new List<Type> { service };

        var temp = x.Bind(serviceTypes.ToArray())
            .To(implementation)
            problem 1====>.WithParameters(properties
                .Select(y => new NamedParameter(y.Key, y.Value)));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            problem 2====> temp.Keyed(key, service);
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is based on nopCommerce DI management.

Comment: Why in the name of love and sanity would you want to move from Autofac to Ninject? What features are you missing from Autofac?

Comment: @Steven I understand your reply :) although written "I would like to move to ninject.." it should be - "I'm forced by evil bosses to move make core changes related to ..." =)

Comment: I personally don't get the excitement about trying to pretend that there's any difference of consequence between any of the lot of them. Regarding what you're trying to do... You can definitely implement an extension method that sits into the fluent definition Syntax and does stuff like this. What I don't get is why you need to abstract or wrap this - pick a container and stick with it. Abstracting away (esp the registration aspects but same for all) of DI container integration doesnt actually get one anywhere. Do you have a strong requirement to be container neutral? Can you just drop that?

Comment: `.Keyed` maps to .Named, For with `.WithParameters` you'll have to look in the code to see if anything other than calling `.WithConstructorArgument` in a loop is goign to do be possible